# C# - passing a variable to another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to pass a `User user` variable to another form, but for some reason it says that it's value is `null`. What did I do wrong?

**AuthorizationForm.cs**:

```
public partial class AuthorizationForm : Form
{
        public Model.User user;

        private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            user = mCollection.Find(u => u.Email == loginBox.Text).FirstOrDefault();
            // Logic, which shows, that in this scope user is not null
        }
}
```

**MainForm.cs**:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
        View.AuthorizationForm authorizationForm = new View.AuthorizationForm();

        private void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // NullReferenceException thrown here because `authorizationForm.user` is null.
            MessageBox.Show(authorizationForm.user.Name);
        }
}
```

Comment: Where in your `MainForm` class are you calling `authorizationForm.Show()` or `authorizationForm.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Since you are instantiating `AuthorizationForm` from the `MainForm` -- you could seed it at that point or later in your progam execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding constructors to AuthorizationForm

```
public partial class AuthorizationForm : Form
{
        public Model.User user;

        public AuthorizationForm()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            user = mCollection.Find(u => u.Email == loginBox.Text).FirstOrDefault();
            //------------------------------------
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the input variable to the `constructor` when creating an instance of the `AuthorizationForm` class.

```
public partial class AuthorizationForm : Form
{
      public Model.User user;
      public AuthorizationForm(Model.User _user)
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          user = _user;
      }   

      private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          user = mCollection.Find(u => u.Email == loginBox.Text).FirstOrDefault();
          // Logic, which shows, that in this scope user is not null
      }
}
```

Or in the first form the user variable separately

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
        View.AuthorizationForm authorizationForm = new View.AuthorizationForm();
        authorizationForm.user = yourVaule
        //...................................................
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the WinForms designer requires Form subclasses to have a parameterless constructor (thus making a mockery of dependency-injection patterns).

Comment: Don’t forget to call `InitializeComponent()` from within the ctor.